# Quit the program with specific letter

Tags: c

I started C programming today.

I want to write a program that keeps asking the user to supply an integer as input until the user tells the program to stop by entering a value of 'q'.

So far I have got this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
   int x;
   while ( x != "q") {
       printf("Enter the integer: ");
       x = getchar(); 
    }
return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
Enter the integer: 1                                                                                    
Enter the integer: Enter the integer: 1
```

and I can't get the program to quit.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: We're in C, so `x` is uninitialized at the first `while`

Comment: Also: OP, didn't you get any warnings from the compiler? A C compiler **must** issue diagnostics for this code, for example *"warning: comparison between pointer and integer"*. You should consider any warnings given by a compiler as errors!

Comment: Invoking the unloved "while"-loop's step sister "do-while" would avoid the necessity to initialise `x`.

Comment: And since `x` was used uninitialized, you invoked *Undefined Behavior* by using *"The value of an object with automatic storage duration is used while it is indeterminate (6.2.4, 6.7.9, 6.8)."*, see [C11 Standard - J.2 Undefined behavior](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.2) (keep the link to the actual standard handy -- you will need it time and time again over the next few years it takes to get truly proficient in C -- you will never learn it all...)

Answer (score 1):

A character constant is written with single quotes: `'q'`.`"q"` is a string literal - an array of characters that decays to a pointer to a first character. Hence the warning given by the compiler

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:5:14: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
    while ( x != "q") {
              ^~
```

Here is the correct code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    // loop forever. Easier to make the condition to exit with if + break

    while (1) {
        printf("Enter the interger: ");

        // declare where it is used, to avoid it being used uninitialized
        int x = getchar();

        // if an error occurs or there are no more input, x equals to EOF.
        // to be correct, the program will need to handle the EOF condition
        // as well. Notice the single quotes around 'q'
        if (x == EOF || x == 'q') {
            break;
        } 
    }
    return 0; // main defaults to return 0 in standard C ever since 1999,
              // so this could have been omitted.
}
```

or the `do { } while` loop could work too:

```
    int x;
    do {
        printf("Enter the integer: ");
        x = getchar();
    } while (x != EOF && x != 'q');
```

however that might not be as nice because since the condition is now inverted and therefore harder to read, `x` needs to be declared outside the loop and you probably *do* need to do some processing for values other than `EOF`/`q` so you'd need an `if` anyway.

---

As for the double prompt - that will happen because the newline `'\n'` is a read character too.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is only a little mistake, instead of `while (x != "q")` try out `while (x != 'q')`.

Comment: While the odds aren't that high- since x isn't initialized before the while loop, it may hold the value of `'q'`, aborting immediately. It should actually be `char x = '\0';` to be correct.

Comment: This answer is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple logic.

This is what you require...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x;

    while(x != 'q')
    {
        printf("Enter the integer: ");
        x = getchar();

        //clear buffer or do this
        getchar(); //this is required to avoid taking newline '\n'
                   //as the input (i.e. when you hit enter)
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The question should have been

**"How to quit a program ONLY by a specific letter and without pressing *'Enter'*?"**

Note: *My answer doesn't answer it.*